# Is there a non-linear version of ICA?

Tags: machine-learning, approximation, learning-theory, sparse-matrices

"Independent Component Analysis" is this : someone is sampling a random vector $s \in \mathbb{R}^d$ such that all its components $s_i$ are mutually independent and $\mathbb{E}[s_i^4] < 3$ and the observer has access to only a transform of it as $y = Ws + b$ where $W$ is a full rank $d \times d$ matrix and $b \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Now the question is to be able to recover $W$ and $b$ from $i.i.d$ samples of $y$.

- Is there a natural scenario where one looks at a non-linear version of this question? Like one has to recover the non-linear transformation applied to the sampled $s$?

Comment: Of course there is [nonlinear ICA](https://www.cs.helsinki.fi/u/ahyvarin/papers/NN99.pdf). Are you looking for examples of usage? A way to look at results / internals?

Comment: Thanks! Has there been any recent work on this? Like what is the state of the art of doing this recovery and/or use?

Comment: Like in the linear ICA we can recover W and b. I guess there is an analogous question of function recovery in the non-linear case too?

Comment: I am not getting you! In linear ICA we do recover W and b. So we do get the "mixing matrix" W. What is your question?

Comment: Has there been any recent work or use of this non-linear ICA?

Comment: More than 20 years, really, have you ever used ICA? Google? I clearly have no clue what you are asking about.

Comment: I haven't seen any recent paper which talks of non-linear ICA and hence I am curious.

Comment: Your title asks if nonlinear ICA exists - yes. Then you give linear version as example, calling result the recovery - so as far as you get results you have your recovery. Next is probably inverse ICA, but I do not follow, then you ask about natural setting and in comments about research of using NICA. How exactly is this connected to Computer Science? Have you tried anything? Like actually looking at results of NICA? Have you read anything? Looked at cross-validated?